# Getting a serverless lambda error "Cannot read property 'Fn::ImportValue' of null"

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm experiencing an error when trying to run a lambda locally, I've included the full output below for help.  I've read [63805110](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63805110/unable-to-invoke-aws-lambda-locally-using-sls) but it looks like a different issued based on the error I have.  I've included a snippet of my package.json for reference.  Any help much appreciated.

Thanks,

**Terminal output**

```
jack-MacBook-Pro:test jack$ ./run.sh
 
  Type Error ---------------------------------------------
 
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'Fn::ImportValue' of null
      at _.entries.map (/Users/jack/Desktop/Projects2/test/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/index.js:190:18)
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at BbPromise.try (/Users/jack/Desktop/Projects2/test/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/index.js:188:53)
      at tryCatcher (/Users/jack/Desktop/Projects2/test/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
      at Function.Promise.attempt.Promise.try (/Users/jack/Desktop/Projects2/test/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/method.js:39:29)
      at AwsInvokeLocal.loadEnvVars (/Users/jack/Desktop/Projects2/test/node_modules/serverless/lib/plugins/aws/invokeLocal/index.js:155:25)
      at AwsInvokeLocal.tryCatcher (/Users/jack/Desktop/Projects2/test/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
      at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/jack/Desktop/Projects2/test/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
      at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/jack/Desktop/Projects2/test/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
      at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/jack/Desktop/Projects2/test/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
      at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/jack/Desktop/Projects2/test/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
      at _drainQueueStep (/Users/jack/Desktop/Projects2/test/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
      at _drainQueue (/Users/jack/Desktop/Projects2/test/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)
      at Async._drainQueues (/Users/jack/Desktop/Projects2/test/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:102:5)
      at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (/Users/jack/Desktop/Projects2/test/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:15:14)
      at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
      at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
      at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
      at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:126:23)
 
     For debugging logs, run again after setting the "SLS_DEBUG=*" environment variable.
 
  Get Support --------------------------------------------
     Docs:          docs.serverless.com
     Bugs:          github.com/serverless/serverless/issues
     Issues:        forum.serverless.com
 
  Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          darwin
     Node Version:              10.16.3
     Framework Version:         1.83.2 (local)
     Plugin Version:            3.8.4
     SDK Version:               2.3.2
     Components Version:        2.34.9
 
jack-MacBook-Pro:test jack$
```

**run.sh file**

```
#!/bin/bash

DATA=$(node -e "console.log(JSON.stringify(
{
  Records: [
    {
      Sns: {
        Message: JSON.stringify({
            'test1': '1',
            'test2': 'jacktest'
        })
      }
    }
  ]
}
))")

npx serverless invoke local --function main --data "${DATA}"
```

**Snippet of package file**

```
"semver": "^5.3.0",
"serverless": "^1.67.3",
"serverless-plugin-typescript": "^1.1.9",
"tslint": "5.16.0",
"tslint-eslint-rules": "5.4.0",
"typescript": "^3.3.1"
```

**serverless config file**

```
service: my-test-lambda-using-lambda

frameworkVersion: ">=1.1.0 <3.0.0"

plugins:
  - serverless-plugin-typescript

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x
  stage: dev
  region: eu-west-1

  environment:
    ENV: dev
    DB_HOST: 
    ...

functions:
  main:
    handler: ts/index.handler
```

**Code snippet**

```
export const handler = async (event: Event, context: Context, callback: LambdaCallback): Promise<void> => {
```

**Update to yml file**

```
functions:
  main:
    handler: ts/index.handler
    events: -sns: arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:xyz
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to share the relevant parts of your `serverless.yml`?

Comment: I've updated my question with the yml fie

Comment: If you want your function to be triggered by SNS messages being dispatched then you will have to add an `events: - sns: <my topic>` to your function, see [SNS events](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/sns/).

Comment: thanks, i'm relatively new to this, I've now included a code snippet of the main method that I need to trigger.

Comment: I was talking about your `serverless.yml`, add the event definition to your function definition, i.e. `main:` linebreak `handler: ts/index.handler` linebreak `events:` linebreak `-sns: <my topic>`. Have a look at the example in the linked doc.

Comment: I've updated my question with a snippet of the updated yml file

Comment: please advice?  thanks. Maybe you could provide an example please?